# Аналог QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene в QML

Tags: qt, qml, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview

Чем можно заменить `QGraphicsView` + `QGraphicsScene` в `QML`?

О задаче, где аналог QGraphicsView пригодится: нужно сделать конфигуратор с отображением в 2D и возможностью перетаскивать элементы.

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативами являются QQuickPaintedItem и Context2D. Но следует отметить, что Context2D имеет низкую производительность, поэтому лучше использовать QQuickPaintedItem.